# Cauchy Condensation Test, without $n$, $\ln n$ and hard for Integral Test

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any example for applying Cauchy Condensation Test which is not just includes just $n$ and $\ln n$ and not easy to find with using integral test?

---

My sketch-work for elementary ones, for readers:

Example 1: For $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac1n$$ we will get  $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty 1$$and for $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$$ we will get $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^n$$and more generally for $p>0$ and  $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n^p}$$ we will get $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{2^{p-1}}\right)^n.$$ This will give us easily the result it is convergent if $p>1$, and it is divergent if $p \le 1$, with using geometric series.

But we can find it easily with using integral test, too.

Example 2: For $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n\ln n}$$ we will get $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{\ln2}\frac1{n}$$ and say it is divergent.

But we can find it easily too with using integral test.

We can also put more $n$ or $\ln$ into sequence.