# Prove that $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a positive, decreasing sequence.
How do I prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n a_{2^n}$ converges? I don't even know where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can start by knowing the conditions and test for convergence and break out terms, adding and subtracting term-wise.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test.

Comment: Someone can look this question too. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738387/cauchy-condensation-test-without-n-ln-n-and-hard-for-integral-test

Comment: @studentforever How is your linked question relevant?

Comment: It is not related directly. Here, the question is about proving CCT, the other is about just CCT. I just said "someone can look too".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about marry...ing terms together. One way (the elements are displayed for the case $N=3$):

\begin{align}
 \sum_1^{2^N-1} a_k  & = (a_1) + \left(a_2+a_3\right)+ \left(a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7\right)\ldots \\
 & \le   a_1 + 2a_{2}+ 4a_{a}\ldots \\
& \le   \sum_0^{N-1} 2^k a_{2^k}
\end{align}
by monotony.

Return:
\begin{align}
 \sum_0^{N-1}   2^k a_{2^k} & = \left(a_1 + a_2 \right) + \left(a_2+a_4+a_4+a_4\right)+a_4\ldots \\
 & \le   \left(a_1 + a_1 \right) + \left(a_2+a_2+a_3+a_3\right)+2 a_4\ldots \\
& \le   2 \sum_1^{2^{N-1}} a_k
\end{align}

by monotony again. If one series is convergent, its limit bounds the other because the latter  is a sum  of positive terms, hence increasing and bounded, hence the other converges too.

As said in one comment, it is called [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test). The figure below  illustrates the way series are bounded:

[image: Cauchy's condensation test illustrated]

Answer (score 2):

The proof follows by prof. Rudin's book, *PMA, page 61, Theorem 3.27*.

Let 
\begin{align}
s_n&=a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n,\\
t_k&=a_1+2a_2+4a_4+\cdots+2^ka_{2^k}.
\end{align}
For $n<2^k$,
\begin{align}
s_n
&\le a_1+(a_2+a_3)+\cdots+(a_{2^{k}}+\cdots+a_{2^{k+1}-1})\\
&\le a_1+2a_2+\cdots+2^ka_{2^k}\\
&=t_k.
\end{align}
On the other hand, for $2^k<n$,
\begin{align}
s_n
&\ge a_1+a_2+(a_3+a_4)+\cdots+(a_{2^{k-1}+1}+\cdots+a_{2^{k}})\\
&\ge \frac{1}{2}a_1+a_2+2a_4+\cdots+2^{k-1}a_{2^k}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}t_k.
\end{align}
Therefore the sequences $\{s_n\}$ and $\{t_k\}$ are either both bounded or
both unbounded, which implies $\sum a_n$ and $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ are either
both convergent or both divergent.

Answer (score 1):

Since the sequence is positive and decreasing, for each $n$ we have
$$2^na_{2^n} = 2 \cdot 2^{n-1}a_{2^n} = 2 \sum_{i=2^{n-1}+1}^{2^n} a_{2^n} \le 2 \sum_{i=2^{n-1}+1}^{2^n} a_i$$
Summing over $n$ then yields
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^na_{2^n} \le 2 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$$
So your series converges.

Comment: What about the "only if"?